# Bluetooth module vs wireless module Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+, hc-05

My main question is, what is the main difference between HC-05 Bluetooth module and NRF24L0 wireless module?

Which should I buy?

Which makes these 2 modules different than each other?

Which one should I use in remote control arduino projects?

Which one is made for what purpose?

Comment: do you want to communicate between two arduinos or with a device which has bluetooth?

Comment: I m talking of Both of the cases @Juraj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the main difference between HC-05 Bluetooth module and NRF24L0 wireless module?

The main difference is the protocol they use. While some attempts have been made with varying success to get the nRF24L01+ to emulate Bluetooth it is not designed for that. You can only really get rudimentary beacon mode working and that only partially.

nRF24L01+ modules can only communicate with other nRF24L01+ modules. They use their own proprietary protocol that is incompatible with any other system. That's not to say they're bad - they're great modules, and the same RF core and protocol is used in many many other devices by Nordic that are used all over the place - the most notable of which is wireless keyboards and mice.

The HC-05 though is a Bluetooth module which is designed to talk to anything else that also talks Bluetooth - such as your phone or computer. It presents an "SSP" profile and gives "master" mode operation to emulate a serial port connection between your Arduino and any other device that knows about Bluetooth and SSP.

The biggest difference in how they work though is when it comes to connecting devices together. Bluetooth devices have to be "paired" before they will communicate. nRF24L01+ devices don't. This means that getting Bluetooth devices to talk to each other takes a certain amount of time and effort, but nRF24L01+ devices are ready to go the moment they are powered on. It's then just down to your software to set up addresses and such to target the communication.

For Arduino-to-Arduino communication the nRF24L01+ is far less trouble as you set everything simply in your code. There are "LNA+PA" variant boards available that include an amplifier and antenna for longer range communication (I have had 300m+ out of those quite happily).

If you want to communicate with anything else, like your phone or computer, then you will want Bluetooth. Otherwise you will have to add an nRF24L01+ to your computer or phone through USB and (probably) another Arduino, which just gets messy.

Comment: Very well explained, I choose HC05 then

Answer (score 0):

NRF24L01+ module is a RF module and HC-05 is an Bluetooth module

It depends on the application you want to perform and what suits best for your application

nrf24l01+ is a great module but it can have issues if you want long distance communication also if you want to increase the distance then there is a module which comes with an antenna

On the other hand It seems that Hc-05 offers 10m range theoretically but according to one the arduino forum [link](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=236324.0) its 15m when in line of sight but if there is some obstacle than it falls drastically

What is the distance you want to cover from the remote control it will specify which best suits you

Comment: Well u didn't mention what the max range is of the nrf24l01